# Unexpected T_ECHO while defining variable inside of while loop

Tags: php, echo

I've been looking at this for hours and am getting ready to give up.  I'm getting an unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) error.  I know this means I have misused/misplaced echo so I have tried numerous combinations of quotes to figure it out, but alas I have failed.  Here is my code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$img = '<img src="/upload/"' . echo $row['image'] . '"/>';
printf('<li id="page_%s">%s</li>', $row['Item_ID'], $img);
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Remove the `echo`, you're already inside PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echo isn't a function, it's a language construct and can't return anything.  Instead of using echo, you would just concatenate directly.  Also, remember to use `htmlspecialchars()` around any arbitrary data to ensure you're generating valid HTML.  And finally, you have extra quotes in your HTML attribute for `src`.  Try this:

```
$img = '<img src="/upload/' . htmlspecialchars($row['image']) . '" />';
```

If you want to make this nice and clean, consider a template engine such as [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Comment: Thanks for the response, however this is not giving the intended result.  What I would like to do is display the image, tied to the Item_ID. However, what is happening is the name of the image is printing rather than the actual image being displayed.  Any ideas why the image name is displaying rather than the actual image?

Comment: @user3785167 Show your output HTML.